# Python: Writing output to text file, but text file does not contain the entire string and truncates randomly?

Tags: python, xml, text, sbml

I am parsing an xls file using Python then converting that information into [SBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBML) (a version of XML).

```
from mod2sbml import Parser

s = open('sbmltest3.mod', 'r').read()
p = Parser()
d = p.parse(s)

outfile2 = open('sbmlconvert.xml', 'w')
print >> outfile2, d.toSBML()
outfile2.close()
```

This is a fairly long file (>3000 lines) and when I open the .xml, the string is truncated randomly around 1400 or 3000 lines. However, when I type: `print d.toSBML()`
and print this string to console, the string is not truncated and I can see the end of the parsed string.

What could be the problem here?

**Edit:** To further dissect the problem, I have closed the code with outfile2.close() and also tried to print s and print to console in my script. This returns both truncated `s` and `d` strings. However, when I type the exact commands into the interpreter separately, both print correctly. Anyone know what's going on with this discrepancy?

Comment: You forgot to close the file. While that probably isn't the reason, you should really do that. Additionally, you can use `outfile2.write(d.toSBML())` instead of using `print`.

Comment: Why do you think that `s` is truncated, especially if `d` seems to contain its full contents?

Comment: Also, you should use "rt" and "wt" as file modes if you are dealing with textual information inside the files. (And "rb" and "wb" if the files are not text)

Comment: @jsbueno: `open` defaults to text mode, so `"r"` and `"w"` will be text mode and `"rb"` and `"wb"` will be binary mode. @Kirk Strauser: What @ThiefMaster means is that `outfile2` should be closed.

Comment: @KirkStrauser It seems that s and d are both truncated if I print them in my script, but are not when I type the commands in the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from mod2sbml import Parser    
p = Parser()    

with open('sbmlconvert.xml', 'w') as of:   
    s = open('sbmltest3.mod', 'r').read()    
    d = p.parse(s)
    of.write(d.toSBML())
```

Comment: Same issue. The problem actually seems to be the read() function. s is showing up as truncated.

Comment: `of.close()` isn't required since you are using a `with` statement.